# ASP.Net || iTextSharp in dotnet cannot use iTextAsian

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I am having trouble with iTextAsian which cause me done nothing but finding solution all this week, it would be great if I can have the solution here.

My situation is I have a project which is using iTextSharp for a while, I had two blocks of code as following, please note that both of them are worked for me

Block 1:

```
Private Function aFunc() as returnType
    iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian")
    )
    Dim font As Font = MyPDF.GetFont
End Function

Protected Friend Shared Function GetFont() As Font
            Return New Font(
                    BaseFont.CreateFont(
                    "STSong-Light",
                    "UniGB-UCS2-H",
                    BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED
                )
            )
End Function
```

Block 2 (current)

```
Public Shared Function GetChineseFont() As iTextSharp.text.Font
    iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian")
    )

    Return New Font(
            BaseFont.CreateFont(
                "STSong-Light",
                "UniGB-UCS2-H",
                BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED
            )
        )
    End Function
```

I am using iTextAsia2.1 and it used to work fine for me, but it start to pop me ""Font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized."" exception on my development server since last week.

The weirdest thing is the version of my website between dev and production server are same, but this block of code worked only on production server, I am wondering whats the matter and I am afraid that one day this exception will appear on my production server.

Please suggest me some solution please.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, I finally figure it out, its because the following block should not contains in a Shared function

```
iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian")
)
```

I now called this line in Application_Start of global.asax and the problem is solved, thanks for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Are you taken update?

The error will come when some clash between older version and newer version or font missing etc. please check this link.

http://www.excindex.com/web/831818.html

http://www.csharpcode.info/ask-235324.html

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Asian-font-not-recognized-after-update-td2991134.html

http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch09.html

Before you start anything, What I think, you just download your production all dll and put in your local development. Check wheather the issue solved

Comment: Nope, I have update nothing but the code, I know there is a similar problem in Java version of iTextAsian which cause by update, but I just changed the code and run...

Comment: No issue with that comment, just check my second comment i.e. check the production dll in local environment

Comment: Tried and still throwing exception, I am thinking that maybe not the dll / code problem..

Comment: Try to run and verify the whole source code of production in local by iis, same as we access as site url or check the same your source to another pc with same environment

Comment: It throw the same exception, so should I assume that some codes in the old version make the iTextAsian works fine but I removed them in the new version?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally changed the permissions of iTextAsian. Or maybe the server no longer has access to it for some Windows-related reason you aren't aware of. In any case: if it works on one machine, but not on another, you have a configuration problem, not an iTextSharp of programming problem.

Comment: You just add reference local and then run. May be your .net dll in GAC cause error.